# Vue js dynamic table row issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vus js to dynamically create table row, but when i click add new row previous row price texbox value gets cleared.Here when i select product i set price textbox value

But when i manually type price value and click add new row, price value not cleared, but i want to get price value from axios call only

Please help me to resolve this issue and point me where i'm doing wrong

My Template Code:

```
<tr v-for="(invoice_product, k) in invoice_products" :key="k">
<td scope="row" class="trashIconContainer">
  <button class="btn-outline-danger btn-sm rem_row" type="button" @click="deleteRow(k, invoice_product)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>       
</td>   
<td>
      <select id="product" name="product" v-model="invoice_product.product_name" @change="setprice($event)">
            <option v-for="(spro, index) in supplierproducts" :key="index" :value="spro.id">{{ spro.name }}</option>
          </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="textbox text-right" type="text"  v-model="invoice_product.product_price" 
    />
</td></tr>
```

My script Code:

```
data() {
    return {
      errors: {},
      valid: true,
      suppliers: [],
      supplierproducts: [],
      input: {
        supplier: ""
      },
      invoice_subtotal: 0,
        invoice_total: 0,
        invoice_tax: 5,
        invoice_products: [{
            product_name: '',
            product_price: ''
        }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setprice(e)
    {    
      this.axios.get('/getproduct/' + e.target.value).then((response) => {        
        if (response.status == 200) {
          e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = response.data[0].price
        }
        else {
          console.log(response.data);
        }
      })
    },
     addNewRow() {
        this.invoice_products.push({});
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Always remember changing data instead of changing dom in vue, and vue will
   automatically help you change the dom
2. Always remember  providing default value for a reactive data.

```js
<tr v-for="(invoice_product, k) in invoice_products" :key="k">
<td scope="row" class="trashIconContainer">
  <button class="btn-outline-danger btn-sm rem_row" type="button" @click="deleteRow(k, invoice_product)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>       
</td>   
<td>
      <select id="product" name="product" v-model="invoice_product.product_name" @change="setprice(invoice_product)">
            <option v-for="(spro, index) in supplierproducts" :key="index" :value="spro.id">{{ spro.name }}</option>
          </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="textbox text-right" type="text"  v-model="invoice_product.product_price" 
    />
</td></tr>

data() {
    return {
      errors: {},
      valid: true,
      suppliers: [],
      supplierproducts: [],
      input: {
        supplier: ""
      },
      invoice_subtotal: 0,
      invoice_total: 0,
      invoice_tax: 5,
      invoice_products: [{
        product_name: '',
        product_price: ''
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setprice(product) {
      this.axios.get('/getproduct/' + e.target.value).then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
        //1. Always remember changing data instead of changing dom in vue, and vue will 
         //automatically help you change the dom
          product.product_price = response.data[0].price
        } else {
          console.log(response.data);
        }
      })
    },
    addNewRow() {
     // 2. Always remember  providing default value for a reactive data.
      this.invoice_products.push({
        product_name: '',
        product_price: ''
      });
    },
```